# paperclip gem the file size column isn't correct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I'm using the paperclip gem to store files (photo, video, audio, etc). The file size is set to zero for most of the file uploads. A couple of the jpeg uploads have the right file size. Anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I think it's got something to do with what happens when the file is saved. Paperclip runs imagemagik in the background to create the thumbnails and so on and I think that's when it gets the file size too.

Don't know for sure, but suspect that you've set up the options so it doesn't need to create them so it's never calling the utilities that get the sizes and so on and pulling those values back into the database.